# Compare 2 sheets from different Workbook until a particular row is reached

Tags: excel, vba, compare

Requirement:
1) Copy the desired sheet from another workbook (Book2) to the current, active workbook (Book1)
2) There are 2 types of data - type A and type B - which are clubbed together
Eg: ***Book1***:

```
NV
A 1
B 2
C 3
E 4
EFS files
A A
B B
C C
D D
```

Each type of Book1 is compared with Book2 i.e. keep comparing until you encounter 'Type B' in next row
3) If a match is not found in Book1, copy that entire row from Book3 to Book1 at current position

I have written following code but the copy algorithm is not working fine i.e. it is not stopping when it encounters "EFS files" string in next row:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' ##CODE TO COPY THE DESIRED DEFAULT SHEET TO CURRENT WORKBOOK (BASE)
Dim wkbSource As Workbook, wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shtToCopy As Worksheet

'setting current workbook as destination
Set wkbDest = ActiveWorkbook

'1) add your own file path
fileStr = "\\D:\Book2.xlsm"
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(fileStr)

'2) add sheet name to be copied
'COPY ONLY IF THE SHEET IS NOT PRESENT
Set shtToCopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Default")

'the sheet will be copied after 'Sheet1' of current workbook
shtToCopy.Copy After:=wkbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
wkbSource.Close

' ##COPY ALGO: Copy non-duplicate NV items from Original (Book3) to the newly created base file (Book1)
'    a) Check the B-column of both files
'    b) If mismatch --> skip copying since base is given priority
'    c) If an item is not present in Base, insert it in Base

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim nvStr1 As String
Dim nvStr2 As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim cmpResult As Integer

nvStr1 = "EFS Files"

Set wbkA = wkbDest
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("Default")

Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(filename:="\\D:\Book3.xlsm")
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Default")
iRow = 6

'Loop until value of cell = "EFS Files"
Do While True
    'COPY ALGORITHM
    If varSheetA.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = varSheetB.Cells(iRow, 2).Value Then
        ' Cells are identical. Do nothing.
    Else
        ' Cells are different. Copy the row to Base
        varSheetA.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = varSheetB.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    End If

    iRow = iRow + 1
    nvStr2 = Trim(varSheetB.Cells(iRow, 1).Value)
    cmpResult = StrComp(nvStr1, nvStr2)

    If cmpResult = 0 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
'End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: In your example you have "EFS files" and in your code you have "EFS Files". `StrComp` is case sensitive. Or is it just a typo in your example?

Comment: "EFS Files" is correct. Sorry for typo in example.

Comment: is `varSheetB` the correct sheet to check for "EFS Files"?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct: The code is working. I made a mistake in checking the output. Thanks for the support. Am sorry if I ended up wasting your time!